# Is it ok to use MATLAB ''freqs" command for Digital filters?

Tags: matlab, filters, frequency-response, digital-filters

According to my understanding, IIR filters are somewhat analog as they are based upon analog prototypes such as butterworth,chbeyshev etc. Can we use`freqs`command to display frequency response of digital IIR filters? If we can use this command for IIR filters then what about FIR filters?Can we also use this command for FIR filters?

Comment: In case you have trouble discerning between them, freq***S*** deals with the Laplace operator, $s$, and freq***Z*** deals with the $z$-transform.

Answer (score 3):

For discrete-time filters, such as FIR and IIR filters, the appropriate Matlab function is [freqz.m](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html). You need to evaluate the frequency response on the unit circle of the complex plane; `freqs` evaluates along the imaginary axis.

Comment: Please reconsider the OP question and your answer. OP is also explicitly asking about IIR filters that are based upon analog prototypes

Comment: @DSPCS: I've read the question and it's all in my answer. IIR filters are clearly discrete-time filters; it's totally irrelevant how they are designed.

Comment: @DSPCS It doesn't matter how the digital filter was arrived at: directly digital or from analog prototypes, if the filter is a digital filter then `freqz` is the right thing to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `freqz` to calculate frequency response of a digital filter and `freqs` for an analog filter.

Given a transfer function of an analog filter
$$
H(s) = \frac{b_0s^n + b_1s^{n-1}+\ldots +b_n}{a_0s^n + a_1s^{n-1}+\ldots +a_n} \tag{1}
$$
we calculate the frequency response by letting $s=j\Omega$
$$
H(j\Omega) = \frac{b_0(j\Omega)^n + b_1(j\Omega)^{n-1}+\ldots +b_n}{a_0(j\Omega)^n + a_1(j\Omega)^{n-1}+\ldots +a_n}\tag{2}
$$

Given a transfer function of a digital filter
$$
H(z) = \frac{b_0 + b_1z^{-1}+\ldots +b_nz^{-n}}{a_0 + a_1z^{-1}+\ldots +a_nz^{-n}}\tag{3}
$$
its frequency response can be derived by substituting $z$ with $e^{j\omega}$
$$
H(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{b_0 + b_1e^{-j\omega}+\ldots +b_ne^{-jn\omega}}{a_0 + a_1e^{-j\omega}+\ldots +a_ne^{-jn\omega}}\tag{4}
$$

It can be seen that these two ratio of polynomials are not identical. Eq. (4) is the ratio of DTFT of sequence $b_n$ and $a_n$, thus [MATLAB uses FFT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html#algorithms) to compute the frequency response in `freqz`, while in `freqs`, it uses [polynomial division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqs.html#algorithms).